# Return multiple solutions GNU Octave or Matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a function that solves for a variable in an equation. There should be 2 solutions to the equation. For example, 9=x^2, x can be 3 or -3. How can I get both values to be returned? Right now it only returns the first answer, 3.

Comment: Please post your code. It will help us answer your question. We don't know what methods you are using to solve the equation.

Comment: are you using a root finding method like newtons method?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your function to return an array of values, for example

```
function x = solve_square(y)
    % Returns the solutions to y=x^2
    x = [sqrt(y), -sqrt(y)];
end
```

Usage would be

```
>> x = solve_square(9)
x =
     3   -3
```

Comment: Also, remember that you can give a name to each element of the return array, like: `function [x1,x2] = myFunction() ... x1=2; x2=4; end`. Then, you can call it: `[sol1, sol2] = myFunction();`

Comment: Yes, if you know a priori how many solutions the function will return then this is viable.